# Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')'

Tags: java, spring, aop

```
@Before("excution(public void show())")
```

**Error:**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position 16
>       excution(public void show())

Comment: Shouldn't `excution` be `execution`?

Comment: @Pshemo, please turn your comment into an answer in order to close the question by the OP accepting the answer.

Comment: @kriegaex If that is the real problem then question should probably be closed as caused by simple typo (which is why I posted it as comment).

Comment: It is pretty obvious that this is the problem. The OP seems to be an absolute AspectJ beginner, so small mistakes like this can always happen. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: @Pshemo already answered the problem by comments. I’m adding details to  give additional details.

Try this one, probably it will work for your problem. adding * ( astrik) will give you the wildcard support.

```
@Before("execution(* show())")
```

For more details on how use pointcut api refer to this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts)

Comment: I think it is not nice to steal someone else's answer without even explaining what was wrong with the original code and without mentioning that @Pshemo actually solved the problem by his comment.

Comment: @kriegaex i didn’t mean to steal @Pshemo’s solution. i thought of asking to use wildcard and also thought of presenting him documentation link. anyway thank you for point me my mistake. i really appreciate your comment.

Comment: Yeah, only the wildcard does not resolve the "pointcut is not well-formed" error. The typo fix does.

Comment: @kriegaex i agree with you, I'm not denying the fact.